# Snowflake: OUTER APPLY / LATERAL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake apparently doesn't support OUTER APPLY. However it has LATERAL, which from what I can see, works like OUTER APPLY.

But when I try to use LATER in this way, I get a compilation error that I'm not sure how to resolve.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
    temp_report r
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL
            (
                SELECT
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rr.state_code ORDER BY rr.priority) as rule_priority,
                    *
                FROM
                    rule_rules rr
                        LEFT JOIN rule_classes rc ON rr.state_code = rc.state_code AND rr.class_group = rc.class_group
                WHERE
                    r.state_code = rr.state_code AND
                    (r.class = rc.class OR rc.class IS NULL) AND
                    ((r.years = 0 AND first_term = true) OR (r.years > 0 AND first_term = false)) AND
                    (r.years-1 % rule_interval = 0 OR rule_interval IS NULL)
            ) rr
WHERE
    rr.priority IS NULL OR rr.rule_priority = 1
```

The error I get is : Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated.

Suggestions?

Comment: Please share sample data and desired results, to make sure the community is solving the correct problem

Comment: It might be the way you're using it, this syntax I think works


SELECT *
FROM departments AS d,
LATERAL (SELECT top 1 e.employee_id FROM employees AS e
         WHERE e.department_ID = d.department_ID) AS iv2  ;

Comment: I've messed around with it, and apparently LATERAL doesn't support ORDER BY. I could re-write the query with LIMIT 1 and ORDER BY at the bottom instead of using ROW_NUMBER, but neither approach works. This is pretty unfortunate. I'm not really sure what a potential solution is here since Snowflake doesn't support OUTER APPLY.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be quite tricky ! Does this help with your problems ?

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
    temp_report r
        LEFT JOIN LATERAL
            (
                SELECT
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rr.state_code ORDER BY rr.priority) as rule_priority,
                    *
                FROM
                    rule_rules rr
                        LEFT JOIN rule_classes rc ON rr.state_code = rc.state_code AND rr.class_group = rc.class_group
                WHERE
                    r.state_code = rr.state_code AND
                    (r.class = rc.class OR rc.class IS NULL) AND
                    ((r.years = 0 AND first_term = true) OR (r.years > 0 AND first_term = false)) AND
                    (r.years-1 % rule_interval = 0 OR rule_interval IS NULL)
            ) rr ON TRUE
WHERE
    rr.priority IS NULL OR rr.rule_priority = 1;
```

Here are a few things to note:

I replaced `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` with `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` and added `ON TRUE`. I think this will ensure that you get all records from temp_report and only matching records from the subquery.

If the error still persists, you might want to further simplify the  subquery. Sometimes, breaking a complex subquery into Common Table Expressions can help.